# How to find the index of the first and second Uppercase Letter in a string?

Tags: java

If there is an input of `string s`. I want to loop through the whole string and break the string into smaller strings, with the string starting with an Uppercase letter and ending with an integer.
For example, if the `string s = "X32Y"`----> the substring would be `X32` and 'Y'. I have found the first time it encounters an uppercase letter, which is `int a`, but I'm stuck on how to find the next upper case which is for example `Y`. I currently used `a+1`, which set the end as the first time it encounters an uppercase `+1`. which would result in `X3` instead of `X32`. Can someone please help find a way to find the next Uppercase? In such a way that `"AX32Y"` become `["A", "X32", "Y"]`. Please disregard the `"A1"`. comment, that is unnecessary, `"A"` is what I want.

```java
public String Password(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) {
            int a = s.indexOf(s.charAt(i));
            System.out.println(s.substring(a, ** a + 1 ** ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is using [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) an option?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Instead of ``int a = s.indexOf(s.charAt(i));``, why not just use ``int a = i;``?

Comment: Thank you, for that, I'm pretty sure it's equivalent and much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to do all at once, without keeping track of state (searching for uppercase or not) and without some variable holding the string you are building.

It's hard to post an exact answer since the requirements aren't very clear, can the string contain other characters than uppercase letters and numbers, what happens if there are two uppercase letters in a row etc?

But just to show you the general idea here is a solution that works for the string "X32Y"

```
public String password(String input) {
  StringBuilder builder = null;

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);

    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
      if (builder == null) { // Start building a new string
        builder = new StringBuilder();          
      } else { // This is the upppercase "after" the string, return what we have
        return builder.toString();
      }
    } // There might be an else here depending on the requirements but we add anything
      // else to the string we are building

    if (builder != null) {
      builder.append(c);
    }
  }

  //If we reach this far return what we got or an empty string
  return builder == null ? "" : builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for not specifying the string. No, the string only contains uppercase letters and Numbers, and if for example, the string is "AX32Y", it becomes "A1" "X32".

Comment: Your method returns a String but "A1" "X32" are two strings or rather a collection of Strings so you need to adjust my answer for that. Hint, create a local variable ArrayList and add to it rather than returning and then at the end return the list instead. Also, "A1" makes no sense. Where does 1 come from in that string? You don't need to answer but  hopefully you have enough to solve this yourself now.

Comment: Yes, im sorry, it does return 2 strings, I had more code in my constructor, but for simplicity sake, I deleted the code, this code was what you said, creating a local variable array list, and adding those substrings into the array list. Regarding "A1", I know it doesn't make sense, that's because I have another constructor, that if there is a string with just 1 Uppercase letter, it adds the integer of 1 to it. This "A1", is just relevant to the project, not necessarily the code in general.

Comment: @Leo So if a letter without a number implies the number `1`, why doesn't that apply to the `Y`? E.g. why wouldn't `"AX32Y"` become `["A1", "X32", "Y1"]`? You should edit the question and explain about the `1`, so all the rules you want applied are described in one place. People shouldn't need to read comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

`String::indexOf` is not too helpful here because it requires a specific value which is sought (e.g. in the given example it would be `str.indexOf('Y')`).  So if a plain iteration by the characters in the string is allowed, it should be done this way:

1. for current char, check if it is an upper case letter
2. if yes, pickup the digits until they end or end of the string occurs

**Update**

There was an update in the comments to the [@Joakim Danielson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66942296/13279831) that a suffix `1` needs to be added to single letters, and a regular expression also allows to provide this preprocessing using `String::replaceAll` and a lookahead `(?=)`:
`s = s.replaceAll("([A-Z])(?=\\D|$)", "$11");`

- `([A-Z])` find a group consisting of a single capital letter
- `(?=\\D|$)` ...followed by NOT a digit OR at the end of the string `|$`
- and replace with the first group `$1` followed by `1`

```java
String s = "ABC123QX32Y24Z";
s = s.replaceAll("([A-Z])(?=\\D|$)", "$11");
System.out.println("inserted 1 between letters: " + s);
```

Then the preprocessed input can be efficiently split into `LetterDigits` parts using regular expressions:

```java
String[] parts = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]\\d+").matcher(s)
    .results()
    .map(MatchResult::group)
    .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println("after regexp: " + Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output

```
inserted 1 between letters: A1B1C123Q1X32Y24Z1
after regexp: [A1, B1, C123, Q1, X32, Y24, Z1]
```

---

Similar solution based on iterating the string and collecting the parts into an `ArrayList` could look like this:

```java
List<String> parts2 = new ArrayList<>();
String part = "";
for (int i = 0, n = s.length(); i < n; i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        boolean digitFound = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            char d = s.charAt(j);
            if (Character.isDigit(d)) {
                if (!digitFound) {
                    digitFound = true;
                    part += c;
                }
                part += d;
            } else {
                if (digitFound && part.length() > 0) {
                    parts2.add(part);
                    System.out.println(part);
                }
                part = "";
                i = j - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (part.length() > 0) {
            parts2.add(part);
            System.out.println(part);
            part = "";            
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("loop: " + parts2);
```

Output for the same input String `s`:

```
A1
B1
C123
Q1
X32
Y24
Z1
loop: [A1, B1, C123, Q1, X32, Y24, Z1]
```